# How to fix the File or path too long exception in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, path

I am making the webrequest to some websites. I do not know the length of the url, since I am getting it dynamically. So for some urls I am getting this error:

"**The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.**"

**var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
  var response = request .GetResponse();**

I am sending the url of the requested page in "url" and I should get the html page, but in response I am getting "path too long exception".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: better cut down your url - to change that limit you need to say what iis you use.

Comment: Hello Aristos, I am using IIS 7.Is there any setting that I can specifiy in web.config for this?

Comment: One more, this error is not for the URL, are you sure that is from URL ?

Comment: Have you read this article about **Long Paths in .NET** **http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx**

Comment: **var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
  var response = request .GetResponse();**

I am sending the url of the requested page in "url". I should get the html page. But in response I am getting this path too long exception.

Comment: Could you show us value of the url variable when exception occurs

Comment: Thank you all.I am not able to reproduce that exception again.I am no more getting this exception. :)